# Static and Extension Method Strategy

Tags: c#, static

I'm working on a personal helper library for my projects. 
I have a lot of helper class and extension methods for my library but I can not decide this helper class namespaces and method to static or extension?

In which case the methods should be static? `StringUtility.ToBase64("xxxx")`
In which case the methods should be extension-static? (I know extensions must be static) `"xxxx".ToBase64()`

How can i determine strategy easily for this behaviours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/01/12/framework-design-guidelines-extension-methods.aspx

Answer (score 4):

My decision is following: "Is this method doing something **with** the object it is extending, returning somethind and doesn't change the extended object" then I use extended methods. I use static class methods when those helper functions do some other which deals with the type of object. I hope that helps you a bit.

Comment: thanks for advice,
can you give a example for "I use static class methods when those helper functions do some other which deals with the type of object"